# Update PartialView with new data without erasing the old data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have the following scenario.
On my page I got checkboxes and a submit button, which sends the formcollection to a method in the controller. The method return a PartialView which is an own cshtml file which gets displayed on the same page with the previously checked boxes. 
My problem is the following: I want to update the partialview everytime I hit the submit button with the new checked boxes without erasing the last ones.
At the moment whenever I hit the submit button it loads the partialview completly new.
How could I save the boxes in the partialview that have been checked already?

Yours,
craft

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Results", "Retrieval",
        new AjaxOptions
        {

            UpdateTargetId = "result"
        }))
    { ..... }
```

Controller Retrieval

```
public PartialViewResult Results(FormCollection collection)
    {

        return PartialView("Test", collection);
    }
```

and Test.cshtml shows the checked data

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: I edited a bit because there is just too much I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the InsertionMode to `InsertAfter`.  See [this list of enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.insertionmode(v=vs.118).aspx) for the [AjaxOptions property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.insertionmode(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help. After I submit I get the values from the checked boxes  and display them in the partialview test.cshtml. Afterwards I want to check other boxes and submit them. What happens is that I got the values of the previously checked boxes replaced by the newly submitted checked boxes values.

Comment: You may want to use JQuery then, which gives you full control over the request.